# Gerar os dias da semana atual?

Tags: php

Preciso gerar os dias da semana atual de domingo a sábado e armazena-los em um vetor no formato `dd/mm/aaaa`, tenho o seguinte código para pegar a semana atual:

```
$diaAtual = date('w'); 
$semAtual = date('Ymd', strtotime('-'.$diaAtual.' days'));
```

O vetor teria que ficar dessa forma:

```
$dias(7){
 [dom] => '13/08/2017', 
 [seg] => '14/08/2017', 
 [ter] => '15/08/2017', 
 [qua] => '16/08/2017',
 [qui] => '17/08/2017', 
 [sex] => '18/08/2017', 
 [sab] => '19/08/2017'
}
```

Comment: As soluções não te ajudaram?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar timestamp para isto...fiz um exemplo rápido, mas acredito que possa ajudar, em vez do echo você utilizaria o array:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', $timestamp)."<br>"; 

for($i=date('w');$i>=0;$i--){
   $timestamp = strtotime("-".$i." days");
  echo date('d/m/Y', $timestamp)."<br>";  
}
$fim = 7 - date('w');
for($i=0;$i<=$fim;$i++){
   $timestamp = strtotime("+".$i." days");
   echo date('d/m/Y', $timestamp)."<br>";   
}
?>
```

Comment: No caso eu quero utilizar a semana atual com parâmetro, e não uma data.

Answer (score 1):

A função abaixo funciona assim: se for informado alguma data é gerado a semana da determinada data, se não for informado nada é gerado pela data atual do sistema, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php                   
    function render($date = null)
    {
        $current = is_null($date)
            ? date('w')     
            : date('w', strtotime($date));

        $now = is_null($date)
            ? strtotime('now')
            : strtotime($date);

        $week = ['dom' => '',
            'seg' => '',
            'ter' => '',
            'qua' => '',
            'qui' => '',
            'sex' => '',
            'sab' => ''];   

        $keys = array_keys($week);

        if ($current > 0)
        { 
            $now = strtotime('-'.($current).' day', $now);      
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
            $week[$keys[$i]] = date('d/m/Y', 
                strtotime("+$i day", $now));            
        }
        return $week;
    }


    var_dump(render());
    var_dump(render('2017-08-06'));
```

[**Exemplo OnLine**](https://ideone.com/9DcTv5)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)
- [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php)
- [date](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)